# Login screen reloading endlessly on BQ Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu Edition

Tags: ubuntu-touch, login, data-recovery, home-directory, phone

The login screen on my BQ Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu Edition device is reloading endlessly. The reloading happens so fast that there is no time to enter the pin code of the device.

What I did before:
After different apps crashing repeatedly I decided to move the `~/.cache` folder to `~/.cache.bak`. Afterwards I rebooted the device, logged in once without entering the PIN of my SIM card before and the endless loop started.

What I tried:
Powering off the device by holding down the power button for many seconds. After reboot the login loop starts over again.

My questions:

1) Is there a way to stop this loop?

2) Is there a way to backup or recover the home directory without being able to pass the login screen to enable remote access?

I didn't enable ADB access, as far as I know.